# Laravel storage image not loading

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have stored image in Laravel storage. When I get it, it gets the file path but says page not found,

My controller code,

```
$email = $request['email'];
$first_name = $request['first_name'];
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);
$postdata = $request['user_image'];
$user_name = $request['user_name'];
$myfile = time().str_random();
    $image = $request->file('user_image');
    $user_image = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Image::make($image)->resize(300, 300)->save( storage_path('/' . $user_image ) );
$user = new User();
$user->email = $email;
$user->first_name = $first_name;
$user->password = $password;
$user->user_image = $user_image;
$user->user_name = $user_name;
$user->save();
```

File path I get when I call the file,

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/1553413340.png
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, the  public disk uses the local driver and stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to  storage/app/public. This convention will keep your publicly accessible files in one directory that can be easily shared across deployments when using zero down-time deployment systems like Envoyer.

To create the symbolic link, you may use the storage:link Artisan command:

`php artisan storage:link`